# Reducing query for top 10 referrals

Tags: mysql

I have a table "RefferalLog" like below keeping track of referrals

| ID | MID | When | IPAddress |

MID = Memberid

Dont know where to even start on how to get the top 10 referring users with the referal count next to it.

Example data in table:

1 21 127.0.0.1 2013-09-13 01:24:19

2 22 127.0.0.2 2013-09-13 07:54:42

3 22 127.0.0.3 2013-09-13 07:56:27

Comment: Start from selecting all users, then sort them, and then limit them..

Comment: +1 because you've used the word 'reducing' which other people may use to find the group by command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) command:

```
select mid, count(*) as totalreferrals
from referaltable
group by mid
order by totalreferrals desc
limit 10
```

The `group by` command groups your data.

The `order by` sorts your groups in descending order (largest at the top).

The `limit 10` restricts the response to 10 answers.

Comment: Thanks, this was killing me!